# clumping the gaps in a CSS grid

Tags: css-grid

So I have a bunch of stuff in a grid.  The following is an extremely reduced example, but demonstrates the issue. The actual grid items have "natural content" sizes, but here I have given them various specific widths in px.  The background colors show the (simulated) content width of the grid items.  In row 2, the items are large and span 3 grid columns.  In row 1, the items are shorter, so the grid algorithm adds gaps between items.

Remembering that the sizes are actually based on content, and are unknown to the HTML & CSS, I would like to control where the grid algorithm places the gaps. As an example, let's say that I would like the gaps for items 1-3, to all be between items 2 and 3, with item 1 left aligned (as it is) with item 11, item 2 juxtaposed with item 1, then a gap, and then item 3 to be right-aligned.  This can be achieved by uncommenting the first grid-template-columns rule.

Now let's say that I would INSTEAD like the gaps for items 4-6 to be between items 4 and 5.  This can be achieved by uncommenting the second grid-template-columns rule.

Now here is the question: is there a different technique that can be used to achieve control over both of these gaps?  Uncommenting the third grid-template-columns rule demonstrates that this technique can only be used in one spot per grid, because the gap sizes are different for the two cases, and it introduces gaps in row 2, which is not wanted.

```css
.gr
{
display:grid;
width:max-content;
grid-auto-columns:max-content;
/* grid-template-columns:auto 1fr repeat( 8, auto ); */
/* grid-template-columns:repeat( 4, auto ) 1fr repeat( 5, auto ); */
/* grid-template-columns:auto 1fr repeat( 2, auto ) 1fr repeat( 5, auto ); */
/* grid-template-columns:auto 1fr repeat( 2, auto ) ??? repeat( 5, auto ); */
}
.wide
{
grid-column:span 3;
grid-row: 2;
}
.w1
{
width:125px;
background-color:yellow;
}
.w2
{
width:110px;
background-color:palegreen;
}
.w3
{
width:140px;
background-color:yellow;
}
.w4
{
width:75px;
background-color:palegreen;
}
.a
{
background-color:red;
grid-row: 1;
width:20px;
}
.b
{
background-color:green;
grid-row: 1;
width:30px;
}
.c
{
background-color:purple;
grid-row: 1;
width:40px;
}
.d
{
background-color:lightblue;
grid-column:span 3;
grid-row: 1;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>grid gaps</h1>
<div class=gr>
<div class=a>1</div>
<div class=b>2</div>
<div class=c>3</div>
<div class=c>4</div>
<div class=a>5</div>
<div class=b>6</div>
<div class=d>7</div>
<div class=b>8</div>
<div class=c>9</div>
<div class=a>10</div>
<div class="wide w1">11</div>
<div class="wide w2">12</div>
<div class="wide w3">13</div>
<div class="wide w4">14</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question, Who is wider the sum of the three grid items on the first row, Orr the single grid item in the second row? Also it would help if you use content instead of random widths.

Comment: @ZohirSalak In the real system, the content produces random widths, very similar to these. It is known that it is possible for (items 1, 2, 3) to be narrower than item 11 (in the example) which causes gaps that would like to be joined together after item 2, but if items 1, 2, 3 are actually wider than item 11 (also possible), then there will be a gap between items 11 & 12, but that is OK. So to answer your question, it might go either way: the 3 grid items might be wider, in which case the gap on the second row is OK, or the single item might be wider—then there should be just one gap.

Comment: @ZohirSalak The last group of three items 8,9,10, are wider than item 14, which demonstrates that other case.

Comment: There's a difference between specifying a width and letting it be auto,  auto widths are treated differently in css grid, That's why it's better if you put up a working snippet with actual content and don't touch the width.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Do you have a reference for how auto widths are treated differently in a grid?  But since the content uses white-space:pre, I'm not sure how auto widths could affect things differently in grid, versus not in grid.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-item-sizing

Comment: @ZohirSalak Thanks for the reference. While I agree that auto widths may be treated differently in a grid than not, after experimentation, none of the options provide any ability to stretch the width beyond the pre-computed size of the grid boxes, which, when they do not consume all the available space for content, seem to get an equal portion of the left-over space, and then the content box can be moved around within the grid box by various options, but never causes the grid box to change size.

Comment: Exactly, That is why i'm asking for an exact replica of your content to work with, There be a hack that can applied to achieve your desired end result.

Comment: @ZohirSalak perhaps you could describe the hack, and I could apply it? While this sample demonstrates the exact problem I am having, the real code is far more complex, and depends on several large fonts.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Is there really a hack?

Comment: There might be. A `hack` isn't a known thing it comes experimenting with the code since everyone has their own use case. Also i only asked for a code snippet mimicking what you have with actual content, Not literally your exact code.

Comment: Well, that's what I posted... a snippet mimicking what I have. I guess you were confused by my remark about "natural content" sizes... the sizes vary more than in my example, and in the real code, the overall width of the boxes includes padding in px or ems, and/or width in px or ems. But spreading out the sizes over left/right padding or width doesn't affect the layout, so for simplicity, I just used px widths here.  So where do the boxes get their sizes? It is derived from content that is overlaid in position:absolute boxes. Like I said, complex. But the snippet accurately reflects the issue

Comment: Instead of using the width property use random text, just enough to give each element the same amount of with.

Comment: @ZohirSalak well, that had an interesting effect, the boxes 1-10 then became sized with approximately the ratio of the contained text, and were stretched to fill their grid cells... but all of the short ones were streatched, rather than just specific ones.

Comment: Now you probably understand the difference between And how it could affect the layout

Comment: @ZohirSalak More than I did. But not enough to solve the posted problem.

Comment: @Victoria, or any other developer, if you want to learn or master CSS grids, then go check out this link: https://learncssgrid.com/
It has almost everything about CSS grids.

Comment: @AbhirajshriWinsome I'm sure the site you mention is a good educational site, but it is irrelevant to mention it if it doesn't address the question asked here.

Comment: @Victoria, this question is tagged with "css-grid". I thought it would be useful to clarify the question that you asked. But if you still don't want it to be, I'll delete that comment